# IntelliJ and Scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij to do some scala development. I normally use Eclipse but was convinced by a friend to give IntelliJ a go. Finding the lack of a 'Problems' view a real pain. But have another problem.

I've got the following code fragement in a test:

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.{Mockito, Mock}
import java.util
...

util.ArrayList aList = Mockito.mock(classOf[util.ArrayList])
aList.add("")
```

So firstly I get a red bar on the right hand side of the editor screen (shame there's no 'problem view'), and when I hover the mouse over it it says `Can not resolve symbol aList`.

Can anyone help me understand this?

If I change the ArrayList import to `import java.util.ArrayList` and remove the prefixs in the code I then get 3 error messages:

```
Can not resolve symbol aList
Reference must be prefixed
Use of postfix method call
```

this is all on the line:

```
 ArrayList aList = Mockito.mock(classOf[ArrayList])
```

So can anyone help me understand this collection of errors? There is no useful help from IntelliJ and a google search didn't shed any light.

Lastly if there is anyone out there who has used IntelliJ and Eclipse for scala+java development could you give me an opinion. It seems to me that IntelliJ is a bit s**t. Or maybe I'm just not getting it...

Thanks All.

Comment: Maybe you should just read up on how variables are declared in Scala. The syntax is `val foo:SomeType = ...`

Comment: Every IDE takes getting used to. I don't develop in Scala, only Java and only in IntelliJ.

Comment: You may find [Twitter's Scala school](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/) helpful.

Comment: OK clever fellas. I changed the line to `val aList = Mockito.mock(classOf[util.ArrayList[String]])` but why do I have to do the prefix on the import thing?

Comment: The 'Problems' view is very advantageously replaced with IDEA's 'Inspections', which are fully configurable. Try "Analyze -> Inspect code".

Comment: Analyze> Inspect Code - Fantastic. Still learning IntelliJ. Can anyone shed light on the 'Referance must be prefixed' error msg?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the prefix: with

```
import java.util
```

you import the util namespace i.e. to access a class within util you have to write util.ArrayList. If you want to import everything within util, you need to write

```
import java.util._
```

to specifically import ArrayList

```
import java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: I understand the above, but why does IntelliJ say 'Reference must be prefixed'? Is there something incorrect about a full class import such as java.util.ArrayList?